# jsonのデータを整列させたい。

Tags: php, api, google-analytics-api

google analytics api で取得したjson のデータをきれいに表示したいのですが、方法がわかりません。各投稿ごとのページビュー数とかをみたいのです。

```
//取得する期間
$from = "2015-03-10";//対象開始日
$to = "2015-04-05";//対象終了日

//取得するデータの組み合わせ
$dimensions = "ga:pageTitle, ga:pagePath, ga:date";//ディメンションの設定[,で区切る]
$metrics = "ga:pageviews";//メトリクス

//取得件数(最大1,000件)
$max_result = 10;

//オプション
$option = array(
    "dimensions" => $dimensions,
    "max-results" => $max_result,
    "sort" => "-ga:pageviews",
//  "start-index" => 50,//オフセット値
);

//トークンのセット
if(isset($_SESSION["service_token"])){
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION["service_token"]);
}

//スコープのセット
$scopes = array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly");

//クレデンシャルの作成
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($client_email,$scopes,$private_key);

//Googleクライアントのインスタンスを作成
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

//トークンのリフレッシュ
if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()){
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($credentials);
}
$_SESSION["service_token"] = $client->getAccessToken();

//Analyticsのインスタンスを作成
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

//データの取得
$obj = $analytics->data_ga->get("ga:{$view_id}",$from,$to,$metrics,$option);
```

です。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

方法は色々ありますが、単純なのはタグ付きで`echo`する事でしょう。
例えば下記の様にすればページビューをpタグで囲えます。

```
echo "<p>pageView:".$obj["totalsForAllResults"]["ga:pageviews"]."</p>"
```

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます:-)